# Why oracle is saying missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

In the following query i am trying to change decimal marker to a `comma`

```
SELECT to_number('12.5678', '99D9999', NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS =', ')  FROM dual;
```

When i execute this query in sqlDeveloper oracle is saying missing right paranthesis. 
Please note that i have locale(DE, Gemany).

What might be the reason?

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL - as opposed to PL/SQL - the third parameter is a string:

```
SELECT to_number('12.5678', '99D9999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS ='', ''')
FROM dual;
```

See also:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions191.htm

Answer (score 1):

`NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS =', '` should be passed as varchar

```
select TO_NUMBER('$94 567,00', 'L999G999D00', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS ='', ''') FROM dual;
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions211.htm#SQLRF06140